# how to compare array object with a number in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

```
$dp=DB::table('vazhipads')
                ->select('dinaparidhi')
                ->distinct()
                ->where('vazhipad','=',$request->vazhipad)
                ->get();
```

this is my query

after dd($dp) i got this result

```
Illuminate\Support\Collection {#1282
  #items: array:1 [
    0 => {#1275
      +"dinaparidhi": 0
    }
  ]
}
```

i want to check dinaparidhi is >0

i tried like this

```
if($dp->dinaparidhi > 0)
{

}
```

but i got some errors

please tell me how to check dinaparidhi>0

Comment: What do you mean by "some errors"? As far as I see, `$dp` is a **collection** of entities

Comment: i got error like this  {message: "Property [dinaparidhi] does not exist on this collection instance.", exception: "Exception",…}
exception: "Exception"
file: "F:\\Devi\\Backend\\devi\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Collections\\Traits\\EnumeratesValues.php"
line: 905
message: "Property [dinaparidhi] does not exist on this collection instance."
trace: [,…]

Comment: Yeah: "on this **collection** instance" is the important information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are sure that you're request return one row, put "first()" instead "get()";
and your condition will work well; if not, you need to do a foreach

Comment: Thank you. I got the correct result when  added first instead of get